# Google Analytics Goal Flow doesn't show all steps

Tags: google-analytics

I have a Google Analytics Goal Setup.
I have a goal, which have 5 non required steps (based on url regex).

When I check the report funnel reports, 
the funnel visualization show all steps, but when I check the Goal Flow report, only the first 3 steps + the goal completion step is being shown.

Is there a way to expand the view of the Goal Flow report?

Comment: Please share your goal & funnel setup, and sample URLs that a user would go through for each step.